# Inserting a row into only column B

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I've written a macro to copy a row from Sheet 2 and inset that row into Sheet 1. My problem is that I only wish to insert the row starting at Column B on the active row. Here is the macro:

```
Sub addTestProductRow()
Sheets("Macro templates").Range("B2:J2").Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Currently my macro does this:
If the user has selected the cell K2 and executes the macro, the Row will be inserted from K2 to S2

What I want the macro to do:
If the user has selected cell K2 and executes the macro, the Row will be inserted from B2 to J2

Things to note:
The row contains a check box so that has to be copied across, currently my macro does copy and paste the check box correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown`

to:

`Sheets("nameOfOtherSheetGoesHere").Range("B2").Insert Shift:=xlDown`

Rather than relying on the selection, specify the sheet and range where you want the insert to take place